# Explanation of Unweighted Shortest path definition from Introduction to Algorithms by Cormen et al

Tags: graph-theory, algebraic-graph-theory

From [Introduction to Algorithms by Cormen et al](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-046j-introduction-to-algorithms-sma-5503-fall-2005/):

We are given a directed graph `G = (V,E)` and vertices ${u,v}\in V $ and then the define **Unweighted shortest path** to be :

> Find a path from `u` to `v` consisting of the fewest edges . Such a
>   path must be simple , since removing a cycle from a path produces a
>   path with fewer edges.

I know what simple path means . I think it means that basically no edges will be repeated in the path from `u` to `v`  but what does "removing a cycle from a path produces a path with fewer edges" mean ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply speaking, if we have vertices `v1, v2, v3, v4, v5`... and our path contains a cycle eg `v1 -> v2 -> v4 -> v3 -> v2 -> v5` we can travel from v1 -> v5 over fewer edges by eliminating the cycle  `v2 -> v4 -> v3 -> v2`, leaving the path `v1 -> v2 -> v5`